# How can I correctly implement collision in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, 3d, augmented-reality, aframe

I am learning A Frame in JS and, while I am able to load in my .glb model and walk around, I don't seem to be able to prevent any collision with the walls or floors. I got the physics working somewhat I think, but I fall through the floor. Can anyone identify what I might have done wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A-Frame GLTF Viewer</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe-mobile-controls/v0.5.0/dist/aframe-mobile-controls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v4.0.1/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene physics="gravity: -9.8">
      <!-- Load the GLTF model -->
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="model" src="lounge.glb"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>

      <!-- Place the camera in the center of the model with a lower height -->
      <a-entity id="rig" position="0 1.0 0">
        <a-camera look-controls wasd-controls-extras="fly: true" kinematic-body></a-camera>
      </a-entity>

      <!-- Load the GLTF model into the scene with physics enabled -->
      <a-entity gltf-model="#model" static-body></a-entity>

      <!-- Enable mobile look controls -->
      <a-entity mobile-controls="controlType: motion"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If its just for walking around, i'd try a [navmesh](https://github.com/AdaRoseCannon/aframe-xr-boilerplate/blob/glitch/simple-navmesh-constraint.js)